# Overlapping partition in core.async

Tags: clojure, core.async

In Clojure I can get overlapping partitions of a collection by tuning the `step` argument to `partition`:

```
(partition 3 1 (range 20))

;; ((0 1 2) (1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5) ...)
```

core.async does have a partition function but since it doesn't accept a step argument, I can't get overlapping partitions:

```
(let [c (chan)]
  (go (doseq [n (range 20)]
        (>! c n)))

  (go-loop [p (async/partition 3 c)]
    (when-let [v (<! p)]
      (prn v)
      (recur p))))

;;[0 1 2]
;;[3 4 5]
;;[6 7 8]
```

I realise having this would probably mean being able to read the same value from a channel more than once. I'm also aware that I could create my own function that reads as many values from a channel as I want and build my own partitions.

However I was wondering if there is any way I could achieve this with the core API provided by core.async.

PS. `sliding-buffer` doesn't do the trick as I can't peek at the whole buffer at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to create a function that reads from the channel, buffers the values and puts to a new channel. I'm not sure how idiomatic this is though.

For example, the function below will `put!` a vector into the output channel whenever the required `n` items have been read from the input channel, skipping `step` items after every output.

```clj
(defn stepped-partition [in n step]
  (let [out (chan)]
    (go-loop [buffer []]
      (when-let [v (<! in)]
        (let [new-buffer (conj buffer v)]
          (if (= (count new-buffer) n)
            (do 
              (put! out new-buffer)
              (recur (subvec new-buffer step)))
            (recur new-buffer)))))
   out))

(def original (chan))
(def partitioned (stepped-partition a 3 2))

(go-loop []
           (when-let [v (<! partitioned)]
             (println v)
             (recur)))

(async/onto-chan original [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])

;=> [1 2 3]
;=> [3 4 5]
;=> [5 6 7]
;=> [7 8 9]
```

Comment: Hmm, also probably best to use the array copy method from the async/partition source as opposed to this with vectors which will probably eat up memory?

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had done. It doesn't seam core.async would make it any easier. I'll mark yours as accepted since it's close to what I have.

Comment: Re: eating memory, `clojure.core/subvec` does indeed produce vectors that hold on to the original input vector, so the internal buffer will eventually hold on to all the values put on the channel (and the vectors put on the `out` channel will hold on to the values seen up to the point when they were produced). One simple fix would be to call `vec` on the result of the `subvec` call on each iteration; the result will be a fresh vector constructed in linear time. Alternatively, you could use [core.rrb-vector](https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector) for real (non-view) O(log n) slicing.

Comment: Agreed that it's probably best to just use arrays, though.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, I think that this desire

> "being able to read the same value from a channel more than once"

Is contrary to the principles of core.async.

**Each time you read a value from a channel you are taking out this value from a channel**

So, the good thing about channel behaviour is that it guarantees one single read for each value, no read (blocking/parking thread) if no value, and nil if the channel is closed.

Then, the next question to start solving your problem should be: why (on core.async) there are at least 3 different functions to put/take values on/out a channel.
So, thinking the communication channel as a rendezvous, there are (core.async) 3 different application/thread behaviour until the reader and the writer are available:

- Blocking thread `>!! <!!` The running thread will be blocked until both, the reader, and the writer are available.
- Parking thread (using go macro block) `>! <!` The go block will create a pseudo-thread that will be park until both, reader, and writer are available. This behaviour doesn't block your running thread.
- Asynchronous behavior `take! put!` You are only guaranteed on the order of writes and reads